# Zener diode purpose

Tags: voltage-regulator, diodes, zener

Can someone explain what the purpose of D3 & D4 are in this circuit?

[image: Voltage regulation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stand it will clamp any negative voltage to < -12.6V due to the zener+diode in series.  This is typically done in environments where secondary induced transients occur. The car industry will typically include lightning protection

Reverse protection (due to installation) is provided by D2. Assuming C1 is large enough to absorb the energy from a positive strike, there is no need to place a positive acting 12V clamp.

Since this is expected to be installed in a a 12V power system, D3 on its own would present a problem in a reverse installation problem.

Comment: Very good explanation, but note that the circuit is probably not meant for car / industry since the max voltage on a car when alternator is charging the battery is around 14.2V, which would be too big for the reverse voltage protection.

Comment: that is true. The transients the automotive industry see's are higher (even higher). There was no source information as to where this came from. This is why I stated there are industries which must deal with transients but I didn't state this was used like this in the automotive.

Answer (score 4):

The **action** of D3 and D4 is to clamp the input voltage at around negative 13-14V.  I see this, and I look at the action of D2, and it makes be believe that the **purpose** is for some sort of protection against connecting the board up backwards.

However -- without a fuse between that part of the circuit and the power input connector, what that circuit implements is a device for burning up zener diodes.  None the less, it's clearly *intended* to be for reverse protection.

Answer (score 0):

We don’t know where you got this schematic.  But we know the LDO reverse voltage and I/O polarized caps must be protected from reverse voltage.

This scenario would be useful when driving an inductive load with LDO and power is disconnected from input on the high side creating a large negative voltage spike of certain stored energy level if greater than the energy stored in the caps.

The diode and Zener would then clamp the voltage bus to -13V if it had no such protection useful for disconnect transients.

I do not see any practical use for these but there may be situations with other peripherals sharing the input that may be offended by a large negative spike when power is pulled.

A similar scenario often blows Buck converter FETs when the output LED load is disconnected intermittently with large positive voltage spikes to drivers during inductor charge source currents.